# Error when creating H2O context using RSparkling

Tags: r, rstudio, h2o, sparklyr, h2o.ai

I am running Spark 2.4.4 using Yarn and interfacing using RSparkling and Sparklyr

As per [these](https://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.4/latest-stable/doc/rsparkling.html) instructions I've

1. Installed Sparklyr
2. Called the library for Sparklyr
3. Removed any prior installs of H2O
4. Installed the latest version of H2O (rel-zorn)
5. Installed rsparkling 3.36.0.3-1-2.4
6. Called the library for rsparkling
7. Specified my spark_config()
8. Successfully made a connection to Spark using Yarn
9. Ran h2oConf <- H2OConf()

When I try to make a H2O context using the h2oConf above I get the following error:

```
Error in h2o.init(strict_version_check = FALSE, https = https, insecure = insecure,  : 
  unused argument (cacert = conf$sslCACert())
```

I've tried multiple different versions of RSparkling and H2O and have been unsuccessful connecting.

Is there some obvious step that I'm missing? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Solution:
Based on feedback from @Marek Novotny below I discovered that I had a reference to an old version of H2O in my namespace. Once I unloaded the package I was able to resolve this issue and moved on to the [next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620857/h2o-cluster-not-finding-local-host-when-running-on-yarn-spark-2-4-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your environment still contains old H2O R library. `cacert` is an [valid parameter](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/jenkins-rel-zorn-3/h2o-r/h2o-package/R/connection.R#L68) and it was introduced in H2O 3.26.0.6.

Comment: I've removed all references to old H2O installations using # REMOVE PRIOR INSTALLS OF H2O
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

Comment: Is there something else I should be doing to flush out old versions?

Comment: What do you get when you execute:
`packageVersion("h2o")`?

Comment: or `getNamespaceVersion("h2o")`

Comment: getNamespaceVersion("h2o") returned an old version of h20. I am in the process of restarting R and unloading the namespace to clear any old references.